# Javasound Clip.isActive should return true if the Clip.start is invoked

Tags: java, javasound

As I understand, `Clip.isActive` returns true if the clip is redering or capturing audio.  `Clip.start` should begin the playback of sound, so `clip.isActive` should be returning true in the following code.  But `"loop"` never gets printed.  I've tried with a `while(true)` loop and the `Clip` plays fine.  Have I misunderstood `Clip.isActive`?

```
AudioFileFormat fileFormat  
AudioInputStream stream;
try{
    fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new File("Sound Files/Firion Battle.wav"));
    stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("Sound Files/Firion Battle.wav"));
}catch(IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
    // exception handling omitted
}
Clip clip;
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, fileFormat.getFormat());
if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)){
    // error handling omitted
}
try{
    clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(stream);
    clip.start();
    while(clip.isActive()){
        System.out.println("loop");// only here for debugging purposes
        // loops until clip stops playing
    }
}catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException e){
    // exception handling omitted
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hot link to an audio clip (load it directly from the code, using a `URL` to the clip). 2) Note that the `Clip` typically runs on a daemon `Thread`. Whether or not that is relevant, will become clear when you produce the MCVE.

Comment: @gpasch I, for one, don't intend sifting though 1400 LOC for a problem that can be expressed in < 25 LOC (e.g. as seen in the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info))! Note that the text `[mcve]` will auto-expand to [mcve]. Less typing, more information, with (hopefully) a better result. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too, but I think that you should do `isRunning` instead of `isActive`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).